# How to access an array in an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I was wondering how to access an array in an array.

This works with a string in an array:

```
NSLog(@"titleName:%@", [[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:0] titleName]);
```

That is, I have an array myLibrary in which I store different classes, each of which has a string for a titleName. In each class I also have arrays and I was wondering how to get access to those arrays. I tried this, but it won't compile as xCode tells me I'm missing an ]:

```
NSLog(@"titleName:%@", [[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:self.currentNoteBookNumber] tabReference objectAtIndex:tid]);
```

Sorry if this is basic, but I'd appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mr Xcode is right. You missed out the bracket after tabReference.

```
NSLog(@"titleName:%@", [[[self.myLibrary objectAtIndex:self.currentNoteBookNumber] tabReference] objectAtIndex:tid]);
```

Comment: ... but that doesn't make sense. I have two [[ to open and then three ]]] to close?

Comment: sorry, its [[[ to open... I should have known. Sorry to have bothered you with this.

Comment: Sure! I tried to do this earlier, but it said that I needed to wait for a couple of minutes. Thanks so much again for your help!